# How to query in CouchDB by docType?

Tags: android, couchdb

I'm trying to use the below query to get my documents by passing the value of docType [template or audit]; however, it is not showing the correct results.

```
Data.getData(database, "audit").run();

public static Query getData(Database database, final String type) {
    View view = database.getView("data");
    if (view.getMap() == null) {
        view.setMap(new Mapper() {
            @Override
            public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
                if(document.get("docType").equals(type)){
                    emitter.emit(document.get("_id"), null);
                }
            }
        }, "4");
    }
    return view.createQuery();
}
```

Comment: What results are you expecting and what results do you see? It looks like you are returning a list of document ids from your query - is that what you want?

Comment: @IanC I want to return a list of documents that contains the docType equals "audit". It is returning for me sometimes nothing or everything.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you might want to creat an index like this:

```
function (doc) {
    if (doc.type) {
        emit(doc.type, doc._id);
    }
}
```

The above function creates an index for you sorted according to `doc.type`. Then you can do your queries faster.